# Getting Rails error 500: logs pointing to passenger and gmaps

Tags: ruby, api, google-maps, passenger, geocode

I am currently running a rails app in production. Whenever i try to access my home page i get an error 500. This started happening recently so i have successfully run the app before.

I realised that i could access some of my inner pages and this problem seems to be common on pages using google maps api. So i figured it could be one of two things: since I am on a shared server host, i might have done something that compromised my rights and now gmaps cant make calls. Alternatively, it could be something to do with my API key, thought i have tested it and confirmed that it is working.

Thank you, I appreciate any help.

IK

This is my log:
Processing HomeController#home (for XX.XXX.XXX.XXX at 2010-08-06 12:12:07) [GET]
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering app/views/home/home.html.erb

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass) on line #51 of app/views/home/_home_left_content_area.html.erb:
48: @short_article_list.each { | article |
49:   address = String.new
50:   address = article.related_location.location_name + " " + article.related_location.parent.location_name + " " + article.related_location.parent.parent.location_name
51:   result = Geocoding::get(address)
52:   if result.status == Geocoding::GEO_SUCCESS
53:     lat_long = result.first.latlon
54:     lat_val = lat_long[0]

```
app/views/home/_home_left_content_area.html.erb:51
app/views/home/_home_left_content_area.html.erb:48:in `each'
app/views/home/_home_left_content_area.html.erb:48
app/views/home/home.html.erb:13
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:362:in `home'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:441:in `start_request_handler'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:381:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:252:in `safe_fork'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:377:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:222:in `start'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rails_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:247:in `spawn_rails_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rails_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:145:in `spawn_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:278:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
```

Rendering /home/neembusc/neembus/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: appears that "something like"  article.related_location.location_name  is returning nil. Might want to check into that...

Comment: Thank you roger.
I tracked down the issue to a table in my db and recreated it. It is a work around since i haven't really figured out what happened but am able to move fwd. Thanks for your input again.